# how to color rows of gridview, if it is merged with two data tables?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Want to color two data tables with different colors which are merged in single data table and bind to grid view. Tried this but it colors same for all rows.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string setrowcolor = string.Empty;

        if (dt1.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
            {
                setrowcolor = "nearbyfit";
            }

            e.Row.CssClass = setrowcolor;
        }

        if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                setrowcolor = "perfectfit";
            }

            e.Row.CssClass = setrowcolor;
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code:-

i am assuming you are merging your `DataTable` like this:-

`dt.Merge(dt1);`

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
    {
        try
        {                
            DataRow dr1 = dt1.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(i => i["Name"].ToString() == e.Row.Cells[0].Text).FirstOrDefault();                
            if (dr1 != null)
                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
            else
                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Teal;
        }
        catch
        { }
    }
}
```

you can replace `Name` with first column of your `DataTable`

Hop this will help you.